# Override interface with string

Tags: typescript

Can we override interface by string in TypeScript?

For example:

```
type RankList = "Manager" | "Staff"

interface EmployeeList {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    department: string,
    rank: "Staff",
    manager: string
}

interface EmployeeList {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    department: string,
    rank: "Manager"
}
```

Here, if the employee listed as "Manager", it doesn't have "manager" field, but if their rank is "Staff", then the field will have a mandatory "manager" field, which is their manager.

So far I get by using an optional field like this:

```
interface EmployeeList {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    department: string,
    rank: RankList,
    manager?: string
}
```

But I want to make it more strict. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions). Basically you can create a type/interface which will hold the common fields like `id`, `name`, `department` and have two separate interfaces one for `Manager` and the other one for the `Staff`. Then you can create a employee type which is basically a *union* of staff and manager types:

```
type RankList = 'Manager' | 'Staff';

interface EmployeeListCommon {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  department: string;
}

interface ManagerList extends EmployeeListCommon {
  rank: 'Manager';
}

interface StaffList extends EmployeeListCommon {
  rank: 'Staff';
  manager: string;
}

type EmployeeList = StaffList | ManagerList;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBASghgOwNYBkCWBnYUC8UDkAsonAOYQBO+UAPgQMrBwBmz+A3AFCdoLCXM4AY2gBRALZgANgHsQECOiwBhGePEyEUAN6coUNABMAXFCwVepLvoRxxEU+cvWohiGDgVg9vo+AWEK04AX25efgpBEShiW3IKJWwIAA9+BEMMKAlpOQVE1XVNHT0oCkQkUyISeI4QsL4BYWhGFmZEqBS0jKzJWXlFTGACjS1dfTLkSpbWWv1xaso-AKDQzlBIHpz+9rxptsHaGIWEwa4gA)